# Argentina not showing up on world map with d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, maps, geojson, topojson

I have a problem with drawing a complete world map using d3.js and a geojson file. The file I am using is https://gist.github.com/phil-pedruco/10447085, and here you can see that all the countries are showing properly, but when I try to render it, I get all countries except argentina. I have also tried using these files: https://github.com/rusanu/geodata-rails/tree/master/vendor/assets/javascripts. Here the 110m file gives me the same result (no argentina), but the 50m file shows the whole map, except it is too detailed and I would rather use the other file.  I have simplified the code to just drawing the paths for the map, to see if there was anything in my code that could be wrong, but the result is the same...Here is the simplified code for drawing the map:

```
    var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
            .center([0, 40])
            .scale(200)
            .rotate([0, 0]);
    var path = d3.geo.path()
            .projection(projection);
    var width = 2000;
    var height = 2000;

    queue()
        .defer( d3.json,"world-110m.json")
        .await(ready);

    function ready(error,world) {
            // console.log(world)
             makeMap(world);
    }
    function makeMap(world){
        var svg = d3.select("#map").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);
         var g = svg.append("g");
          svg.selectAll("path")
                .data(world.features)
                .enter()
                .append("path")
                .attr("d", path)
                .attr("stroke","black")
                .attr("fill","white");

    }
```

Does anyone know what the issue could be, and solutions for how to fix it? Help would be greatly appreciated :)

edit: After trying a whole bunch of different things, I noticed that if I specify "fill:none", argentina is suddenly outlined, but as soon as I specify a fill-color, it disappears...Still have got no idea why this happens -.-

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you see this behavior (a country showing up only via stroke and not via fill) then it typically indicates a corruption of the geodata where the polygon has been turned inside out (it's filling everything *around* the polygonal border). You'll need to take the dataset into a GIS and try to repair it. In this case, it's not actually Argentina, but rather Bermuda that is corrupted. You could delete Bermuda, which seems to work fine, or try to repair the geodata in a GIS application.

The reason it seems like Argentina is missing is because the corrupted Bermuda is being drawn on top of Argentina (among others).

Comment: Thank you! Removing Bermuda works, and I don't really need Bermuda ^^

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the first ~20 countries on the list (Afghanistan, Angola, Albania, Argentina...) were not showing via stroke. I assumed the file was corrupted for those elements, however, I duplicated those same countries and I changed the "ID" in the JSON file (so I had ~20 countries more) and it worked.